# What is the proper way to call getAttributeNS using Java DOM?

Tags: java, dom, namespaces

I'm having a problem correctly calling getAttributeNS() (and other NS methods) from Java DOM. First, here is my sample XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book xmlns:c="http://www.w3schools.com/children/" xmlns:foo="http://foo.org/foo" category="CHILDREN">
        <title foo:lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

And here is my little Java class that uses DOM and calls getAttributeNS:

```
package com.mycompany.proj;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class AttributeNSProblem
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            File fXmlFile = new File("bookstore_ns.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            System.out.println("Root element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
            Element elem = (Element)nList.item(0);
            String lang = elem.getAttributeNS("http://foo.org/foo", "lang");
            System.out.println("title lang: " + lang);
            lang = elem.getAttribute("foo:lang");
            System.out.println("title lang: " + lang);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I call getAttributeNS("http://foo.org/foo", "lang"), it returns an empty String. I've also tried getAttributeNS("foo", "lang"), same result.

What's the proper way to retrieve the value of an attribute qualified by a namespace?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh lord, w3schools...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after `DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();`, add `dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. It would be nice if the Javadoc on the DOM 'NS' methods like getAttributeNS() mentioned this.